# How To Read Chrome Cookies Using Java

Tags: java, javascript, google-chrome, cookies

I am currently trying to read a certain cookie from my Java desktop application. I have used a chrome extension to create the cookie and using the chrome console I can view that it has been created and has the correct value.

The problem arises when I try to read it from my Java application, my current code gets 3 seemingly random cookies, which wouldn't be a problem if it included mine. I have ensured my cookie is not host only and it is not secure, it actually has the same properties as the other 3 but it just is not being returned.

Here's my current code:

Java Application Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.CookieHandler;
import java.net.CookieManager;
import java.net.CookiePolicy;
import java.net.CookieStore;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Spud
 */
public class Reading_My_Created_Cookie
{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    private static final String SEARCH_TERM = "Tab";
    private static final String ADDRESS = "http://www.youtube.com/";
    private static final CookieManager COOKIEMANAGER = new CookieManager();
    private static Object myCookie;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            COOKIEMANAGER.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
            CookieHandler.setDefault(COOKIEMANAGER);
            URL url = new URL(ADDRESS);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.getContent();
            CookieStore cookieStore = COOKIEMANAGER.getCookieStore();
            Object[] cookieJar = cookieStore.getCookies().toArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < cookieJar.length; ++i)
            {
                System.out.println(cookieJar[i]);
            }
            //myCookie = checkForCookie(cookieJar);
            //System.out.println(myCookie);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(Reading_My_Created_Cookie.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private static Object checkForCookie(Object[] cookieJar)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cookieJar.length; ++i)
        {
            if (cookieJar[i].equals(SEARCH_TERM))
            {
                return cookieJar[i];
            }
        }
        return "Cookie not found";
    }
}
```

This currently outputs the following:

```
run:
YSC=6EIDrzvf02s
PREF=f1=50000000
VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE=qKCoNVZQMi8
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

For anyone who wants it, this is my current extension JavaScript code:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(run);

function run()
{
    var cookieName, cookieValue, cookieURL;

    cookieName = "Tab";
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab)
    {
        cookieValue = tab.title;
        cookieURL = tab.url;
        createCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, cookieURL);
    });
}

function createCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, cookieURL)
{
    chrome.cookies.set({name: cookieName, value: cookieValue, domain: ".youtube.com", url: cookieURL});
    alert("cookieName = " + cookieName + " cookieValue/tabTitle = " + cookieValue + " tabURL = " + cookieURL);
}
```

Thank you for your time, I really hope I can get this sorted as it is currently a key part of my A-level computing project.

Comment: So ... you create some cookies inside Chrome via your Chrome add-on, right? And now you expect to go back to youtube.com and get the cookies from there? Why would they be there?

Comment: @Pointy I was under the impression they were stored for that domain by chrome, I can view them when I use chromes console on youtube.com.

Comment: Yes, but your Java code is making a connection to a remote server (youtube.com, which is probably about a zillion servers, and you're connecting to one of them).  Wait - is your Java code an applet?  Or a stand-alone application?

Comment: @Pointy That makes sense, it is a stand-alone application. Do you know of any way that I can retrieve the variable contents from my extension to my stand-alone program?

Comment: Well, if the extension can manage to set cookies that the server will recognize and retain after some sort of form submission or other activity, I guess it's possible, but otherwise the cookies are stuck inside the local storage managed by your Chrome instance.